# Yang-Mills connection on circle bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a connected, oriented, compact Riemann surface with positive constant curvature $K_g$, and let $P\to M$ be a principal $S^1$-bundle on $M$. Can we find a Yang-Mills connection $A$ on $P$ such that the norm of the curvature $2$-form $F_A\in A^2(M,\mathbb R)$ is equal to $K_g$ (i.e. $|F_A|_g=K_g$)?

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to just scale the connection appropriately? For an Abelian gauge group such as $U(1)$ the curvature tensor is just $F_A = dA.$

Comment: A two form is the curvature of some principal $U(1)$-bundle if and only if it has integral periods. So the metric $g$ on $M$ has to have an integral total volume.

Comment: @Tobias Diez  By Gauss-Bonnet  $\int K_g dV_g =4\pi\times \chi(M)= 8\pi$.

Comment: @Arash  You can find such a connection if and only if  $P$  has the same Euler class as $TM$.